# Numba failure on cell assignment

Tags: python, numpy, numba

The following code bombs (the python.exe process fails in Windows) when I run it:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def test():
    array_a = np.zeros((10, 100), dtype=np.int32)
    array_b = np.zeros(100, dtype=np.int32)
    cursor_a = 5
    for i in np.arange(cursor_a):
        array_a[2, i] = array_b[i]

test()
```

The code runs successfully when not decorated with @njit, and without a traceback, I'm struggling to debug. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: 'Bombs'? The process fails? How exactly? Any errors? Are you running this by double-clicking the `.py` file? If so, consider running it from the terminal, then you'll see the error message, if there's any.

Comment: This code runs without error for me using numba 0.32.0. What is your expected result since the code you posted doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

The problem went away when I upgraded from Numba 0.19.1 to 0.30.1